# Как создать Intent в Android для перехода из приложения в WhatApp в чат с указанным в приложением телефоном?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Мне необходимо, что бы при нажатии на пункт меню, у пользователя запускался WhatsApp  с чатом номером телефона указанным в приложении.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("http://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=70001234567"));
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Вместо `70001234567`указываете нужный номер телефона.